# Cordova adds 350ms delay on click() events in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, delay, phonegap

If I use something like `$('button').click(function() { alert('hi'); }` and I add the following to my `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

..and I run it as a normal mobile site on iOS 11, there is no delay (=> expected behaviour).

**However**, if I run the **exact same** code in a compiled **Cordova** hybrid app on **iOS**, the delay is back! (=> not good)

Do I have to start using fastclick.js or some other workaround again like it's 2013? What about other Cordova developers on here: **do you experience the same problem?**

PS: It works fine on Android.

PPS: Adding `touch-action: manipulation;` in CSS doesn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the fastclick issue, apparently, it's a new bug introduced with iOs 11.3.

Here is the [full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500339/cant-prevent-touchmove-from-scrolling-window-on-ios)

And here is a fork which resolves the [fastclick issue with iOs 11.3](https://github.com/lasselaakkonen/fastclick/tree/fix-ios-11-3-event-timestamps)

I'm also looking for a workaround, since fastclick doesn't look to be maintained anymore...

Comment: That's great, thanks. Let us know if there is any new development :)

Answer (score 3):

We experience the exact same problem.

Using FastClick as a workaround works for most iOS versions, except for the latest iOS release: 11.3. 
After a fresh start of a Cordova app, FastClick works as expected but after a while (especially when calling native iOS calls like taking a photo), it shows weird behaviour where your input fields (nested in other divs) do not get selected at all and you have to tap multiple times to select an input field.

I have no clue why the 350ms delay is still active for (Cordova) apps and not for a standard mobile website opened in Safari.

Thanks to the tip from [Romain Le Qllc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160676/romain-le-qllc), I replaced fastclick with the fork that he mentioned (https://github.com/lasselaakkonen/fastclick).
This resolves the issues in both iOS 11.3 and 11.4.

Also big thanks to [lasselaakkonen](https://github.com/lasselaakkonen).