# Can't prevent `touchmove` from scrolling window on iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, mobile-safari, preventdefault, touchmove

We are trying to scroll an element on our iOS web app while preventing the window itself from scrolling. We are capturing the `touchmove` event on the window, scrolling the element programmatically and (trying to) prevent the window itself from scroll by calling `preventDefault` on the event.

Unfortunately this doesn't work in Mobile Safari. The window continues to scroll underneath our element. The issue sounds exactly like the Webkit bug described in https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163207, but that issue was supposedly fixed in iOS 10.3 whereas I am running 11.3.

Catching `touchforcestart` and calling `preventDefault` does seem to prevent scrolling of the window, but we are calling it in `touchstart`, which seems to be "too late" since the window still scrolls. Scrolling is only prevented next time `touchstart` is called.

Any ideas about what is going on? We are baffled since this is clearly a bug but it seems to have been fixed some time ago.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I recently ran into this same problem.  You'll need to pass `{ passive: false }` when registering the `touchmove` event listener.  e.g.

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

This is because document touch event listeners are now passive by default in Safari 11.1, which is bundled with iOS 11.3.  This change is documented in the Safari 11.1 [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_11_1.html):

> ### Web APIs
>
> - [...]
> - Updated root document touch event listeners to use passive mode improving scrolling performance and reducing crashes.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! We are adding our `touchmove` listener inside the `touchstart` handler, and for some reason it seems I need to cancel that even as well (with `preventDefault`) to get the `touchmove` to cancel, even with passive turned off. With both `{ passive: false }` and the `touchstart` and `touchmove` events both canceled after we handle them, it appears to work great.

Comment: Is it possible to enable scroll in specific div only inside the document after applying this code? @user9576791

Comment: How do I remove this event listener on click from a page? @user9576791

Comment: Nice, but the problem now is you're not scrolling the page either.

Comment: @MatthewGertner -- do you mean you add:
```document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });```

Comment: Thank you so much. I kept seeing answers that didn't have the passive part, and so didn't work.

Comment: Awesome! the missing `passive: false` drove me nuts for hours! Thank you!

Comment: how do i pass in the `{ passive: false }` option to a function delcaration?

Answer (score 8):

You need to bind `preventDefault` to two events: `touchmove` and `touchforcechange` to make it work in ios 11, e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.preventDefault, {passive: false});
document.addEventListener('touchforcechange', this.preventDefault, {passive: false});
```

**And you should bind them before touchstart**

If you bind them inside your `touchstart` or `dragStart` handler, they can only prevent scroll in the next dragging.

Comment: `touchforcechange`? it seems to work without that?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to pass the `{passive:false}` option to `addEventListener` ([explanation](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080)), and you also need to make sure you execute `e.preventDefault()` on `touchmove` **and** `touchstart`:

```js
window.addEventListener("touchstart", e=>e.preventDefault(), {passive:false});
window.addEventListener("touchmove", e=>e.preventDefault(), {passive:false});
```