# Prevent Web Page Touch/ Scrolling on Safari in iOS 11 Devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I used to use the following code to prevent web page from scrolling on touch devices (specifically tested on iOS).

```
disableScroll = false;
$(document).on('touchmove',function(e) {
    if (disableScroll) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However since iOS 11 this no longer works. Using iOS Simulator I can go back and test on iOS 9 and iOS 10 and it works fine but no longer on iOS11. Can anyone suggest an alternative solution?

For example, testing this similar functionality on iOS 9/10 works but doesn't on iOS 11. https://benfrain.com/preventing-body-scroll-for-modals-in-ios/

Comment: Alternative might be CSS, adding `overflow: hidden` to the body or the tag that you want to stop the scrolling. I usually have a general class called `.no-scoll` that I apply with JS instead of preventing the default event`

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu Thanks but this doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: OMG, you're right, this is strange...

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this John!?

Answer (score 1):

Similar question but with plain javascript is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49582193

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: you need to bind preventDefault to two events:  touchmove && touchforcechange.  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163207