# How to prevent body scrolling on iOS 12 when modal opened?

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll

**Scenario :**
On iOS 12 none of solutions for iOS 11 doesn't work. 
**Tried CSS:**

```
body.modal-open {
   overflow: hidden;
   position:fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

> And also this

```
body.modal-open {
   touch-action: none;
}
```

**Tried JS :**

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Problem :**

- Is it possible to prevent body from scrolling on iOS 12?

Comment: I just tested this on an iOS 12 device and could not reproduce this problem

Comment: So you mean that even `overflow: hidden;` stops site scrolling on iOS 12?

Comment: Yes, when combined with `position: fixed`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this similar question but with plain javascript is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49582193

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```