# Disable body scrolling when IOS keyboard shows

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have looked around for a solution to this problem and although I have come across other people asking the same question , it seems answers for this issue are limited.

**The Problem**

The issue is that I have a overlay (slide-out from the side) menu which has a search box on it. I need to disable all body scroll so that the user can easily scroll around on the overlay without the body moving all over the place.

**Solutions I have tried**

The solution I have tried is from the link below

[How to disable body scrolling when modal is open IOS only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54786905/9174675)

This solution works great , when the sidebar shows up body scroll stops and when the sidebar disappears body scroll works again.

**Whats wrong with the solution I have already found**

Well , on Ipad when you click on a search box and the keyboard shows up for some reason body scrolling issue once again appears. If I get rid of the keyboard the problem is once again sorted.

**Why is there no code on this page**

I work with confidential data and the code is company property therefore this is not something I can post on here. Now I can mock up an example code which shows the issue however it would literally be a side bar with a search box and I dont think that would be useful however I may be wrong in which case I'm sure I can mock something up.

**Apologies if the lack of code on this page offends anyone.**